# Trouble adding realtime database Firebase onto my project (npm)

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying here after I've(seriously and thoroughly) tried dozens and dozens of Youtube videos, official documentation and sites on google. I have without a shadow of exaggeration tried that much and spent literally 6+ hours on this.

I keep getting few errors, which change from one to the other while i try some fixes.
The Errors are:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".(this one points to the HTML document)

or

> firebase.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at firebase.js:1:1)

I created the realtime database, used npm to install firebase, it is in my .json dependencies also, config is clear, i just added the databaseURL and that's it.

Below is the code(HTML and Javascript file it includes). The code in JS currently simple as i just wanted to try out adding something to the database with the simple form for now.

This html below and I'm pasting a JS screenshot also

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" target="_blank" href="CSS/styledash.css" />
  <title>Kapetan Dashboard</title>
 
</head>
<body>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <img src="SLIKE/SCST.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
  </div>

  <div class="box-form">
    <div class="right">
      <form id="teamForm" class="inputs">

        <label for="ekipa">Naziv ekipe:</label>
        <input type="text" id="ekipa" name="ekipa" required>

        <div class="button">
          <button type="submit" class="spremiEkipu" id="spremiEkipu" onclick="saveData()">Spremi</button>
        </div>

      </form>

  <div class="box-form">
    <div class="right">
      <h5>Unesi Podatke za igrače</h5>
      <form id="playerForm" class="inputs">


        <label for="ime">Ime:</label>
        <input type="text" id="ime" name="ime" required>

        <label for="prezime">Prezime:</label>
        <input type="text" id="prezime" name="prezime" required>

        <label for="brojIgraca">Broj Igrača:</label>
        <input type="number" id="brojIgraca" name="brojIgraca" required>

        <div class="position-container">
          <label for="pozicija">Pozicija igrača:</label>
          <select id="pozicija" name="pozicija" required>
            <option value="napad">Napad</option>
            <option value="sredina">Sredina</option>
            <option value="obrana">Obrana</option>
            <option value="golman">Golman</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="button">
          <button type="submit">Spremi</button>
        </div>

      </form>

    

      <div class="table-container">
        <h2>Informacije o igračima</h2>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Ime</th>
                    <th>Prezime</th>
                    <th>Godine</th>
                    <th>Broj Igrača</th>
                    <th>Pozicija</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!-- Zamijeni ovo sa stvarnim podacima kad ih uneseš -->
                <tr>
                    <td>Primjer</td>
                    <td>Igrač</td>
                    <td>25</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>Napad</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Primjer2</td>
                    <td>Igrač2</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Golman</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Primjer3</td>
                    <td>Igrač3</td>
                    <td>21</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>sredina</td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td>Primjer4</td>
                    <td>Igrač</td>
                    <td>19</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>Obrana</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
            
        </table>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <div class = "button">
    <h6><button type ="sumbit">Odjava</button></h6>
  </div>

 <script type="module" src="./firebase.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So i have installed firebase in my project folder using npm. The dependencies contain firebase. I have also tried using the script tag method or CDN method that firebase provides but i still encountered errors of same nature, and i turned back to npm method as i found it the most intuitive one. I followed official documentation dozen times, creating a new project multiple times on firebase and still got errors. Followed similar questions here on stack overflow but none got me the result